# Json Data to CSS in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have a problem that I really don't know how to tackle... I am working on an Angular app that needs to color some fields. The colors are stored in an XML on the server and are being configured in an external application.

I am planning to read that XML, create a JSON out of it and return it to my app via a webservice and use a json to css library to create the css classes out of that json.

My question is this: Is there a way I can force my angular app to read the css classes from the json/css I just created. When I initialize the app, I call the webservice and when the application loads I should have the CSS... My problem is that I don't know how to tell Angular that it should pick up my new css classes.

Comment: please post your code. You can use ngClass of angular.

Comment: You can use ngStyle

Comment: There is no code since I don't know if this is possible or how I can achieve it. 

I cannot use ng Class since the fields I am trying to color are dynamically loaded, I have no control over them, I only know what class they are. I am not necessarily interested in a code reply as more in a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand you correctly but when you want to add some classes to a html-tag dynamically you can write `class="{{VARIABLENAME}"`and in the variable (string) of the component has to be stored the class name. If you want to add a complete style information just do it with `style="{{VARIABLENAME}}"`.
example: `<div class="{{classnameVariable}}"></div>`
It's also possible to use ngStyle or ngClass for that.

Comment: Not quite... I have some fields that are coming from a webservice. I have no control over them, I am not writing them myself :

field a - has css class fieldA
field b - has css class fieldB ...and so on ... 

I just want to make sure that fieldA, fieldB css classes are the ones from my json file.

From your example, {{classnameVariable}} is always the same... i want to make sure that the classnameVariable css style is picked up from the json.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the data and your html-view?